# window-switching keyboard shortcuts interfere with emacs and cannot be changed in the main keyboard system preferences

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, emacs

As of Ubuntu 16.04, Some emacs key combinations involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> conflict with the keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu. One way to fix this is to go to **System settings > keyboards > shortcuts** and disable / change all the ones that conflict.

A similar question was [asked here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122092/how-can-i-prevent-gnome-from-intercepting-the-altshift-key).

However, there are some shortcuts that are *not* in that setting. For example, in emacs, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick key) is used to open the emacs menu. However, in Ubuntu, it opens up a window switcher with a preview. Similarly, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> toggles the switcher. These shortcut keys are *not* in **System settings > keyboards** *at all*.

How can the windows-switching shortcuts be remapped so that they don't interfere with emacs?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: much simpler answer courtesy of [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122092/how-can-i-prevent-gnome-from-intercepting-the-altshift-key):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['disabled']"
```

**original answer:**

the obvious workaround involves CompizConfig Settings Manager, which can be installed easily as explained in many, many places. However, the steps necessary to remap some keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> are completely non-obvious, due to a possible bug in Compiz.

First, in CCSM, go to **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**. Then go to the last tab, which is labelled **Switcher**, and examine the **Key to flip through windows in the Switcher** (without "backwards") item. It is already disabled, but this is actually what is performed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>. To *really* disable it, enable this feature (with some garbage random key combination).

Note that if you disable it again, then it really is disabled, but after a reboot the bug will return. Hence, to really get rid of <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>, you need to assign it some random garbage key combination, like <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> or something.

There are also some other key shortcuts in Compiz, like ones involving <kbd>Super</kbd> (Mac/Windows icon key on keyboard) that has this bug in Compiz, e.g. it says disabled but is actually enabled.

Also, in CCSM, there is an **Application Switcher** category, as well as a "static" version of it. Those should be disabled if **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** category is enabled, since there are a few conflicting shortcut keys. However, most of the shortcut keys not found in the original Ubuntu **System settings -> Keyboard** page can be found and modified here.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 19.10 there is even more interference.

So far I had to remap the following key-bindings to not interfere with emacs.

You can use dconf-editor to view all the org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings and even edit them.

Here is the list I remapped and what I the remapping is I did using gsettings:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['<Super>Above_Tab']"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super>Page_Down']"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['[]']"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['[]']"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Super>Page_Up']"
```